# What is the proper way of hard-coding sections in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView with 3 sections that are hard coded. Everything is working fine, but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

Define number of rows in section:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger rows;

        //Bio Section
        if(section == 0){
            rows = 2;
        }
        //Profile section
        else if(section == 1){
            rows = 5;
        }
        //Count section
        else if(section == 2){
            rows = 3;
        }
    }  

    return rows;
}
```

Here is where I build my cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 5;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:(10.0)];
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    if ([self.message_source isEqualToString:@"default"]) {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                cell.textLabel.text = [Utils formatMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", mySTUser.bio]];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
            }
            else if(indexPath.row == 1){
                cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", mySTUser.website];
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            }
        }
} //more code exists, but you get the point...
```

Now I define my number of sections

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tblView 
{ 
     return 3;
}
```

Is this the proper way of hard-coding my UITableView? Will I run into any issues when cells are reused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using a `switch-case` tree with an [enumerated type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type), to replace the `if` conditionals that test for various hard-coded integers. [This blog post](http://speirs.org/blog/2008/10/11/a-technique-for-using-uitableview-and-retaining-your-sanity.html) explains this option in more detail. Using `switch-case` with your table view delegate methods will make your code much more readable and flexible. Otherwise, your reuse code looks correct.

Comment: MUCH MUCH cleaner. Thank you!